# Replace all word boundaries excluding certain patterns with an asterisk

Tags: regex, mariadb

I'm working with [Full Text Index in boolean mode](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-text-index-overview/#in-boolean-mode), but I need to replace all the word boundaries (**only word endings**) when the words

- **ARE NOT** Between quotation marks ("This text should be excluded")
- **DONT HAVE** an asterisk at the final of the word (Excluded*)

The pattern that matches the two cases above is

```regex
(".+?"|[\w]+[*])
```

And for word boundaries is just `\b`. The problem is that I cannot create the regex, I tried using the exclusion patern, but I think I'm using it the wrong way

```regex
(?=\b)(?=(?!(".+?"|[\w]+[*])))
```

Something like this

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Word boundaries are zero-width, so how can you "select" them? They can be thought of as locations between adjacent characters, the location preceding the first character of a string or the location following the last character of a string. A word boundary is preceded by a word character and is not followed by a word character or is followed by a word character and is not preceded by a word character.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Basically, I needed to add an asterisk after each word with a length >= 4 that did not already have an asterisk or is enclosed in quotes. To achieve this, I replace the word limits with an asterisk. All this in order to work with [full text index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-text-index-overview/#in-boolean-mode) in boolean mode. It has an application and it works!

Comment: @EduardoJiménez What is the tool or language where you are running the regex?

Comment: Eduardo, when responding to comments asking for clarification you should edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. Questions should be self-contained. Your comment and edit suggest to me that your question is something like, "I wish to add an asterisk to the end of each word that has a length of at least 4 that does not already end with an asterisk and is not within a string delimited with double-quotes. How can I do that?" If you begin with that readers will know where you are going...

Comment: ...Saying (in the title and first sentence) that you wish to "select" word boundaries doesn't make sense (unless you wish to return an array of indices, which is not what you want). btw, I did not downvote.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't tell the purpouse of this because I though it was information to spare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I had to use:

- Negative look behind `(?<!")` to exclude the word boundaries that have a quotation mark before
- Negative look ahead `(?!["*])` and `(?!\s[\w\s]+["*])` to exclude the words that finishes with `*"`
- If you want to select the words with more than n - 1 characters, you can establish a limit `(?<=[\w]{4})`

```
(?<!")(?<=\w)\b(?!\s[\w\s]+["*])(?!["*])
(?<!")(?<=[\w]{4})\b(?!\s[\w\s]+["*])(?!["*]) // Words with lenght >= 4
```

[image]

Comment: In a construction like `(?<!")(?<=\w)` you can omit the `(?<!")` as the second `(?<=\w)` already asserts a word char to the left, so there can not be a `"` as well. The pattern is also depending on that the next "word" does **not contain** an asterix using `(?!\s[\w]+["*])`. It does not say that it should not end on an asterix as there is no boundary specified after the `*` or `"` See this example https://regex101.com/r/jyfXia/1

Comment: Thanks for the information :).  I tried with`Bye "cruel world" dont* say goodbye` and the regex I wrote takes 252 steps while yours 263. I'll look what's going on, because with the text you propose it takes the same steps

Comment: Your second regex matches the zero-width location immediately after `"abcd"` in `"abcd efgh ijkl"`, so if that is converted to an asterisk your string becomes `"abcd* efgh ijkl"`, a no-no.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you wish to add an asterisk to the end of each word that has a length of at least 4 that does not already end with an asterisk and is not within a string delimited with double-quotes.

Assuming your strings are well-formed in the sense that the number of double-quotes is even, you can replace the content of capture group 1 of matches of the following regular expression with an asterisk appended to the content of capture group 1:

```
(\w{4,})(?!\w|\*|[^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"{2}))*[^"]*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Kkv0P/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(\w{4,})          # match >= 4 word characters
(?!               # begin negative lookahead
  \w              # match a word character
|                 # or (alternation) 
  \*              # match '*'
|                 # or
  [^"]*"          # match >= 0 chars other than '"' then '"'
  (?:             # begin a non-capture group
    (?:[^"]*"){2} # match >= 0 chars other than '"' then '"' in
                  # a non-capture group
    {2}           # execute the above non-capture group twice
  )*              # end non-capture group
  [^"]*"          # match >= 0 chars other than '"' then '"'
  $               # match end of string
)                 # end negative lookahead
```

Note that

```
[^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"{2}))*[^"]*$
```

asserts that the current string location is not followed by an odd number of double-quotes (that is, the current string location is not within a string delimited by double-quotes).

---

Another way is to use a regular expression that first attempts to match what you don't want (words within double-quoted strings) and if that fails attempt what you do want that is saved to a capture group, paying no attention to the matches, only to the capture group:

```
"[^"]*"|(\w{4,})(?!\w|\*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/e5bpqf/1)

As you see at the link

```
Cats in "some very* stylish" hats
```

is converted to

```
Cats* in * hats*
```

as it shows *matches* being converted to `$*`, but by limiting the substitutions to capture groups we get the desired result:

```
Cats* in "some very* stylish" hats*
```

Confining the substitutions to capture groups is done programatically, which of course depends on the language being used (which has not been identified in the question). In Ruby, for example, one could write:

```
str = 'Cats in "some very* stylish" hats'
str.gsub(/"[^"]*"|(\w{4,})(?!\w|\/) { |s| s[0]=='"' ? s : $1+'*' }
  #=> "Cats* in \"some very* stylish\" hats*"
```

The two methods I have given are supported by most regex engines. There are, however, other ways of doing this that make use of features supported by limited numbers of regex engines.

Comment: It doesn't work, the result for the first input is `Cats* in some* stylis*h* hats*`. It should be `Cats* in some* stylish* hats*`

Comment: Good catch. I fixed it.

Comment: I was also thinking about the "match what you don't want" approach. I came up with ruling  out all "words" ending on an asterix `"[^"]*"|\S+\*(?!\S)|(\w{4,})`